# How to change aspnetboilerplate "an error occured dialog"

Tags: .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, sweetalert, sweetalert2, boilerplate

I want to change [aspnetboilerplate sweetalert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEU8b.png) to any custom error dialog. I am using ASP.net core with Angular. Whenever there is a exception at server side, this dialog pops up. I can't find the place in code where this sweetalert is used. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can find showMessage() function you need in this file.

> ..\angular\src\assets\abp-web-resources\abp.sweet-alert.js

[image]